# Is there a way to know if an HTML form is currently submitting?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, form-submit

I have a race condition in which I do not want an AJAX call to occur, if a form on the page is currently submitting.

I'd rather not alter the code for the form.

I was thinking of attaching event handlers to each of the form elements so that onsubmit it would increment a counter and then on onreadystatechange decrement the counter.

Then before the AJAX call, check to ensure the counter is zero before firing.

However is there an easier way such as (pseudo code):

```
form.isSubmitting
```

---

EDIT:

The race condition is not because of the JavaScript per-say. It is caused by what happens on the server side on response of the ordering of these actions.

To give you an idea of the broader problem:

A cookie is set when the form post returns.
On the AJAX call (needs to happen every X seconds)... the server-side (if the form post has happened) expects the cookie to be set.

Sometimes....

If there is a delay in the form submission returning (and setting the cookie client side), the AJAX call is triggered without sending the cookie back.

The server expects the cookie, because as far as it is concerned the form post has been successful.

However it is the client side I need to control to ensure the actions are performed in a prescribed way.

So correct JavaScript itself cannot cause race conditions, but (as far as my testing has shown) - the submission and returning of POST/AJAX calls causes a race condition in my particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "race conditions" in Javascript on a web page, because there's just one thread of execution. If you want to prevent event handlers from doing anything after a form has been submitted (or at any time, really), the very simplest thing to do is set some globally-accessible flag. The handler routines just have to check for that. Of course it's important that the flag is cleared when appropriate.

*edit* — OK after your edit, it's a little more clear what you're doing, but one thing is not clear: how exactly is the form being posted?  Is it a "natural" form post?  If that's the case, the whole page is going to be reloaded by the response.  Is the target a separate `<iframe>` perhaps?

Or is the form being submitted by some *other* AJAX code?

1. If the form is being submitted "naturally" by the browser, and we're talking about a whole page being reloaded, then that's probably the simplest case. The form's "submit" handler should simply set the global flag, and the code running via the interval timer should just do nothing on the intervals when the flag is set. There's no need to worry about clearing the flag, because the page is going to blasted by the response anyway.
2. If the form is posting within an `<iframe>` on the page, or posting to a hidden `<iframe>`, then it's almost the same as (1) except that the response page *will* need to clear the global flag. Exactly how to do that depends on what the application setup involves, but basically it'll just be some Javascript in the response that sets `top.postingFlag` to `false` (or whatever).
3. If it's separate AJAX code that's posting the form, then you'd set the flag when you start the XMLHttpRequest, and clear it in the handler(s) for success/failure.

In all cases, the key is for code in the interval timer to watch for the state of the flag, and avoid posting when the flag is set.

Comment: Doesn't setInterval() allow multiple threads to be running at once?

Comment: No - each time a timer routine is called, it's like an event loop from a button click - it will never happen in the middle of another event loop of any kind

Comment: Modern "web workers" are in fact a way to have multiple threads, but they're pretty well "firewalled" from other code so you still really can't have race conditions

Comment: Hi, correct it's not JavaScript per-say causing the race condition... i've updated the question to reflect this. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy. It's a plain form submission i.e. option 1. I wasn't sure if there are any instances where the form submission might fail. Does it always redirect to the next page? Or it there an equivalent event for forms, to onreadystatechange?

Comment: When a form is submitted in the normal, good old-fashioned HTML way, the browser expects the response to be the page it should show. In other words, it's like clicking on an `<a>` tag: the response is going to be treated like the stuff that should occupy the window that the current page is occupying. Whether the post succeeds or fails is not really an issue; the response needs to be something appropriate as a "page". The trick is to have the page include the Javascript snippet to clear the flag.

Comment: Oh but again the flag only needs to be cleared if the "window" is actually an `<iframe>`, and other pieces of the application live on in the client. If the old interval timer was part of the old (replaced after the POST) page, then it's gone anyway so the flag is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to the form tag:

```
<form ... onsubmit="this.setAttribute('isSubmitting', 'true');">
```

And you'll be able to see if it's "submitting" by checking that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, that would work.**

You can submit the form via an AJAX call. That way you can control the `ajaxSend` and the `ajaxComplete` events and have a global variable say `var formIsSubmiting = false` serving as a flag.

Right before the non-form AJAX call check the status of the variable and that should prevent your *race condition*.